# Which Linux distribution is suitable for serverside development and somewhat easy to use?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, centos, distribution-choice

I need to setup a Linux-based server which is going to be the backend for our web services.

This is what I need: (In order of importance)

1. A GUI to manage applications and files
2. It would be running a custom built C++ server
3. Probably also the LAMP stack, if needed.
4. I would be trying out [ERP](http://www.orangehrm.com/) or other serverside software on it also (optional).

Which Linux distribution do you recommend for such a use-case, considering I'm not an expert at any Unix-like OS (a week of experience with CentOS, some experience with Ubuntu).

This is what I understand about each distro:

- **Ubuntu** - easy to use, the most popular, easy to install apps, no hassle
- **Debian** - older, but might be tough to configure
- **CentOS** - troublesome, hard to install apps
- **Mint** - popular, based on Ubuntu and Debian

---

**Edit:** I have a lot of people recommending Ubuntu over CentOS([1](http://knol.google.com/k/tom-harrison/centos-vs-ubuntu/24f5zicu9nl0z/1#), [2](https://serverfault.com/questions/53954/centos-vs-ubuntu)) for serverside apps. Is Ubuntu fine for such things? Its not slower than CentOS or anything troublesome?

And should I go with Ubuntu or Ubuntu Server? what are the advantages of either?

> "Software installation is a breeze on Ubuntu. Even the server applications come with decent default configurations and are normally usable out-of-the-box. It's a software paradise."

Comment: Ubuntu Server! I use Ubuntu server and desktop and find both are very very easy to use/setup. server has no DE by default, and gives a nice little setup menu for configuring your server type. Other than that you just get all of the awesomeness of ubuntu.

Comment: It is important to note you can ***Very Easily*** install Unity or some other DE on Ubuntu Server. It is just not there by default.

Comment: @rlemon - Please add your comments as an answer. They're good. Remove the comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most modern distros (including those you mentioned) have Xorg-based window manager out-of-box. They've got a compiler and a package manager. So the most non-trivial requirement if (4), ERP installation, you should check its documentation and see what it supports best.

As a software developer, I would choose Ubuntu, it's updated often and has zillion packages in 'universe' repo, you set it up, install `ufw` and other tools you need, and you are practically done. However, I would take some 'stricter' distro like CentOS for production.

Comment: So you're saying CentOS is better for production servers? Why?

Comment: It doesn't install a huge bunch of packages by default, it has SELinux enabled by default, IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

[CentOS](http://centos.org) is a clone (binary compatible by design) of the by far most popular enterprise distribution, [Red Hat Enterprise Linux](http://www.redhat.com/products/enterprise-linux/). It isn't hard to handle, just (like all enterprisey distributions) has a limited selection of software out of the box, and feels a bit outmoded if you are into bleeding edge. For extra software that is 100% compatible, look at [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).